# Should I use ASCII encoding for Base64, or Java's default ISO-6559-1?

Tags: java, character-encoding, base64, ascii, iso-8859-1

`java.util.Bases64` uses ISO-8859-1 by default.

Yet Base64 uses only  ASCII   characters.

Of course ASCII is a 7-bit subset of ISO-8859-1, but still, I wonder whether I should use the default or specifically choose ASCII.

Comment: Are you asking about text in a `String` that has a character encoding applied and then Base64 applied: which character encoding?; Or about Base64 in a String that needs to have a character encoding applied before being written out as bytes: which character encoding?

Comment: I'm asking about encoding a byte array as String using Base64.

Comment: Base64 libraries usually take a byte array and return a String. (String is UTF-16, if that's important to you.)

Comment: Yes, this takes a byte array and returns a String. But the encoding for creating that String can be anything. Of course, Strings are not in themselves UTF-16 or any given encoding, but rather the conversion from bytes to/from String is done with some encoding.

Comment: A Java, JavaScript, .NET, VB4/5/6, … `String` is a counted, indexable sequence of UTF-16 code units, with one or two code units per Unicode codepoint. There is no other character encoding for _text_ datatypes in these programming environments. So, you are asking about a String that needs to have a character encoding applied before being written out as bytes, given that it will have only the Base64 characters, right?